# Multiple "<g> attribute transform" errors in kendo UI chart break pdf export

Tags: kendo-ui

I added kendo chart on a page according to the documentation.
But started to get next error 5 times per each kendo ui chart

```
Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "matrix(NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,…".
```

Charts are drawn but those errors break pdf export. When I use same datasource as in my app on kendo ui dojo.telerik editor there is no error.
I know there might be dozens of possible reasons but I'm a bit locked with that for next few days. So I decided to try luck on stackoverflow in case anyone had anything similar.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue on a Kendo Dojo? It's hard to tell without some code..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and for me it was related to the `<kendo-chart-series-item-labels>` component.
I had as property `rotation="auto"` but the rotation property should be only a number. Removing the property solved it.

```
<kendo-chart [chartArea]="{ height: 300 }">
  <kendo-chart-series>
     <kendo-chart-series-item
        type="column"
        colorField="color"
        [gap]="1"
        [spacing]="0.25"
        [color]="barColor"
        [data]="chartData"
        [stack]="true"
        field="TotalSum"
        categoryField="TransactionType"
        [tooltip]="{ visible: false }"
      >
       <kendo-chart-series-item-labels
          font="bold 16px unity-medi"
          color="#3c3c3c"
          rotation="auto"
          [margin]="30"
        ></kendo-chart-series-item-labels>
      </kendo-chart-series-item>
    </kendo-chart-series>
  </kendo-chart>
```

solution: remove `rotation` property inside the `kendo-chart-series-itme-labels` component

Kendo API documentation for this component here: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/SeriesLabelsComponent/

Of course, in your case, it may come from a different component.

Maybe double check if you have a property inside a `kendo-chart` or one of its child component that requires only numbers while you may be passing a string or something else to it?